# Refresh div after closing popup with onunload

Tags: javascript, popup, refresh, onunload

I'm currently using the following code which opens a popup window, and refreshes the parent window when the popup is closed.

**Parent / Open Popup Link Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Begin
function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=500,height=600,left = 433,top = 84');");
}
// End -->
</script>
<a href="javascript:popUp('reminder.php?order=1234&amp;delete')">Open the Popup Window</a>
```

**Popup Window Code**

```
<body onunload="window.opener.location=window.opener.location;">
```

Is it possible to edit this code so that instead of refreshing the entire parent window it only refreshes a specific div (and its contents)? I'm hoping something like getelementbyid could be used.

The popup window is used to delete reminders that are stored in a database. After deleting a reminder I'd just like that div to be blank (indicating thats it deleted). It doesnt need to refresh as such, simply its contents need to be removed.

Thanks :)

Comment: Refreshing only a section of the parent would require Ajax.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a global function in the parent (the opener) and provided they are **on the same domain** you can call it:

```
function clearDiv(){
    document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML = '';
}
```

Then in the popup:

```
window.onunload = function(){
   window.opener.clearDiv();
}
```

Comment: +1. Might want to make the call conditional - if reminders cleared, call the funciton.